# On free shipping how to apply tax in woo commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sales-tax

I have set free shipping above 200$ in my eCommerce site but, I want to apply taxes which is not applying in my cart or checkout page.

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more ? If it is lower than $200 then taxes will be applicable ? like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable tax from woocommerce settings

1.Go to: WooCommerce > Settings.
 2.Select the Enable Taxes checkbox.
 3.Save changes.

You can set up tax in woocommerce following the link https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-taxes-in-woocommerce/